# Partial view not recognising logged in user

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using a scaffolded Partial named LoginPartial that shows the username of the user if they are logged in. However, I don't understand why its not detecting that my user has logged in even though I confirmed it in the controller.

My Partial

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager
@*For some reason this disappears*@
@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    <form asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Page("/Index", new { area = "" })" method="post" id="logoutForm" class="navbar-right">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
                <a asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">Hello @UserManager.GetUserName(User)!</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link navbar-btn navbar-link">Logout</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
}
else
{
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register">Register</a></li>
        <li><a asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
}
```

This is the controller

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var result = signInManager.IsSignedIn(HttpContext.User);
    return View();
}
```

The result that I get from this is always true. However my view page doesn't give me the same results. Could it be because of my recent implementation of custom claims? I have [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52628587/asp-net-core-duplicate-claims-after-logging-in-or-during) that I managed to solve (kind of) and I'm hoping that it isn't related to this issue.

I found that if I comment out my custom claims helper, it starts to work again. This custom claims adds a list of the users roles to the claims so that I can use it for something else.

```
    public class CustomClaimsCookieSignInHelper<TIdentityUser> where TIdentityUser : IdentityUser
    {

        private readonly SignInManager<TIdentityUser> _signInManager;

        public CustomClaimsCookieSignInHelper(SignInManager<TIdentityUser> signInManager)
        {
            _signInManager = signInManager;
        }

        public async Task SignInUserAsync(TIdentityUser user, bool isPersistent, IEnumerable<Claim> customClaims)
        {
            var claimsPrincipal = await _signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(user);
            var identity = claimsPrincipal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
            var claims = (from c in claimsPrincipal.Claims select c).ToList();
            foreach (var item in claims)
            {
                identity.RemoveClaim(item);
            }
            if (customClaims != null)
            {
                identity.AddClaims(customClaims);
            }
            await _signInManager.Context.SignInAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme,
                claimsPrincipal,
                new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = isPersistent });
        }
    }
```

I discovered something that I'm not sure may be related?

[image]

With my custom helper activated, there are 3 claims missing: 2 xml ones and 1 that has a security stamp on it. Compared to the ones without a helper:

[image]

Comment: I'm calling IsSignedIn as a test to check if my user is verified. Its for debugging purposes and is just to confirm if its an issue with my controller or view.

Comment: Also, User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is the same. Nothing shows up.

Comment: I've added an edit to my question. I found the cause of the issue but I can't solve it.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean the end result of those claims? As in what the claims are with and without the helper?

Comment: Hi @CamiloTerevinto, I noticed that 3 claims are missing from when my helper is active. Is it possible to manually add those ones in? The reason I'm clearing my claims is because when I run it on another pc, I'm getting duplicates for some reason.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your custom helper is destroying ASP.NET authentication mechanism by removing essential claims:

- NameIdentifier => the ID of the user
- Name => the Name of the user
- SecurityStamp => the identifier of the current session for that user

Don't remove claims created by Identity (otherwise just don't use Identity) and don't remove claims needed for ASP.NET built-in authentication.

*Note*: the following code is from memory, some adjustment may be necessary for compilation.

```
var claimsPrincipal = await _signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(user);
var identity = claimsPrincipal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
var claims = claimsPrincipal.Claims.ToList();

if (customClaims != null)
{
    customClaims = customClaims
        .Where(x => !claims.Select(y => y.Name).Contains(x.Name));

    identity.AddClaims(customClaims);
}
```

Comment: Sorry just need some clarification. Your customClaims = customClais line, does that mean you are adding the items from the old claims list that have a similar name?

Comment: @JianYA That's the LINQ way of saying "get all items from customclaims where those items' names are not found in the claims variable". That `.Contains(x.Name)` could be seen as a `foreach claim in claims if (claim.Name == x.Name) return true`

Comment: Oh okay. I'll use this code to fix my issue. Thank you!

Comment: I had to do it manually because I can't get .Name from anywhere. This is how I solved it. Its crude but I guess it works?
identity.AddClaim(savedClaims[0]);
                identity.AddClaim(savedClaims[1]);
                identity.AddClaim(savedClaims[2]);
                identity.AddClaims(customClaims);